# How do I determine whether a print material is dishwasher, food, and microwave safe?

Tags: health, food, print-material

I would like to print lunch boxes, which I can put into the microwave.

How could I determine, if the print material is appropriate (dishwasher, food, microwave safe)?

Comment: You should ask a more specific question, like "Is material X when printed using Y process Z safe"? Attempting to stuff information about all possible materials, processes and types of safety in to one question doesn't seem wise.

Comment: I am not familiar with the print materials, so I would like to ask it before I buy one. Btw this is the top voted question in the definition phase. So it is considered a good question by the community.

Comment: This is at least three separate questions.

Comment: well it won't be food safe because most thermoplastics are porous making it great for harboring bacteria. I'm not sure about the others.

Comment: This is a very nice question, with a well define scope and parameters that can be addressed objectively. Expecting "is material X when printed using Y process Z safe?" as a question is an arbitrary expectation: one could object that formulation too is too broad, as it did not ask "...with a nozzle in W material and at temperature T, post-processed with technique Q", for example.  This is a small site, with a tiny community around it.  We should work to make it relevant and helpful.  Comprehensively answering a question like "how to print functional microwave containers" would certainly help...

Comment: Although old it seems a legit and relevant question as of today. I vote to reopen. It also got above average (sadly) upvotes on this site.

Comment: This is an ancient pre-historic question (from before when the site was formed). None of the issues raised in the comments have been addressed - so it is still too broad and needs a narrower scope. A comprehensive answer would need to be many pages long (i.e. almost a thesis), needing to cover differences for X, Y, Z, W and T (as outlined in mac's comment). The OP has had 7 years to make the edits. Admittedly this *could* be a good and useful question. Maybe someone (else) should ask a ***newly formulated*** question (or series of questions) that addresses *all* of the issues in the comments.

Comment: If someone already *has* a comprehensive answer that they'd like to post, or an argument for opening (along with a possible proposal for a narrower edit), then maybe this should be raised in meta, as the comments isn't a good place for discussion.

Comment: @Greenonline I wanted to find printing materials that are dishwasher, food, microwave safe. Not sure how this question should be narrowed further, and then avoid being closed for "XY problem". Should I create a question for each material I find?

Comment: TBH, I really don't know. Maybe, as that is *certainly* narrower (maybe try and see if it gets closed?).  However, I think asking a question on *Meta* first, and asking what you've just asked in the comment, is probably a good idea, then you will (hopefully) get a discussion (and feedback) involving the community that could expand upon the reasons mentioned in the comments above -  and hopefully a consensus arrived at. Discussing in comments is not a good place to discuss.